# creating objects how can I get nested objects too

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, nested

I am creating a constructor function. So I need to get my object everything is good except nested objects, how can i do that part?

```js
function creation(name, value, id, name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.value = value;
  this.category = {
    id: "",
    name: ""
  }
}

let creationOne = new creation('book', 350, 1, "Something extraoridnary");
console.log(creationOne);
```

Comment: You can't have two parameters named `name`.

Comment: Change `id: ""` to `id: id`

Comment: And `name: whatever you rename the second name parameter to`

Comment: can I have the same name but in the different parts, first one is just an objects, second one is nested

Comment: How is it supposed to know which `name` is which?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using ES6 Object Property Value Shorthand

- Rename the first parameter to `bookName`.
- Now you can assign values to the `id` and `name` property inside the `category` object.
- So, you can either do: `this.category = {id: id, name: name}` **OR** simply `this.category = {id, name}`.

```js
function creation(bookName, value, id, name) {
  this.name = bookName;
  this.value = value;
  this.category = {id, name}
}

let creationOne = new creation('book', 350, 1, "Something extraoridnary");

console.log(creationOne);
```

Comment: The `book` argument isn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

You need different names for the two `name` parameters. And then you need to use the parameter variables when creating the nested object.

```js
function creation(object_name, value, id, category_name) {
  this.name = object_name;
  this.value = value;
  this.category = {
    id: id,
    name: category_name
  }
}

let creationOne = new creation('book', 350, 1, "Something extraoridnary");
console.log(creationOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to pass in the category as an object:

```js
function creation(name, value, category) {
  this.name = name;
  this.value = value;
  this.category = category;
}

let creationOne = new creation('book', 350, { id: 1, name: "Something extraoridnary" });
console.log(creationOne);
```